# Traefik with self-signed backend

Tags: kibana, traefik

I have the traefik setup to proxy the kibana backend with self signed certs. Whenever I access the backend, I am getting "Internal error" in the browser and I see the following error message in kibana logs.

> {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2018-02-04T03:56:26Z","tags":["connection","client","error"],"pid":1,"level":"error","message":"139782929405760:error:14094412:SSL
>   routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert bad
>   certificate:../deps/openssl/openssl/ssl/s3_pkt.c:1493:SSL alert number
>   42\n139782929405760:error:140940E5:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:ssl
>   handshake
>   failure:../deps/openssl/openssl/ssl/s3_pkt.c:1216:\n","error":{"message":"139782929405760:error:14094412:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert bad
>   certificate:../deps/openssl/openssl/ssl/s3_pkt.c:1493:SSL alert number
>   42\n139782929405760:error:140940E5:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:ssl
>   handshake
>   failure:../deps/openssl/openssl/ssl/s3_pkt.c:1216:\n","name":"Error","stack":"Error:
>   139782929405760:error:14094412:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3
>   alert bad certificate:../deps/openssl/openssl/ssl/s3_pkt.c:1493:SSL
>   alert number 42\n139782929405760:error:140940E5:SSL
>   routines:ssl3_read_bytes:ssl handshake
>   failure:../deps/openssl/openssl/ssl/s3_pkt.c:1216:\n\n    at Error
>   (native)"}}

Here is my docker-compose file:

```
 ---
 version: '3.0'
 services:
  traefik:
    image: traefik:1.5-alpine
    command: --web --accesslog --docker --docker.watch --docker.domain=localhost --logLevel=ERROR --entryPoints="Name:http Address::80"
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "8080"
    labels:
      - "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:monitor.localhost"
      - "traefik.port=8080"
      - "traefik.frontend.entryPoints=http"
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - /dev/null:/traefik.toml
  elasticsearch:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-platinum:6.1.3
    container_name: elasticsearch
    ports:
      - "9200"
    labels:
      - "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:es.localhost"
      - "traefik.frontend.entryPoints=http"
    environment:
      - cluster.name=docker-cluster
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms1024m -Xmx1024m"
      - ELASTIC_PASSWORD=changeme
    cap_add:
      - IPC_LOCK
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
      nofile:
        soft: 65536
        hard: 65536
  kibana:
    image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:6.1.3
    container_name: kibana
    ports:
      - "5601"
    labels:
      - "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:kb.localhost"
      - "traefik.frontend.entryPoints=http"
      - "traefik.protocol=https"
    links: 
      - elasticsearch
    environment:
      - SERVER_SSL_ENABLED="true"
      - SERVER_SSL_CERT=/usr/share/kibana/config/kibana.example.org.crt
      - SERVER_SSL_KEY=/usr/share/kibana/config/kibana.example.org.key
    depends_on:
      - elasticsearch
```

How can I make traefik to work with self-signed certs? Am I missing anything in the setup?

Answer (score 2):

I've been dealing with this sort of issue myself. Traefik does not currently support per-backend configuration of TLS parameters, unless it's for client authentication pass-through. The only customization currently offered for reverse-proxy routing in a back-end is with the global `insecureSkipVerify` boolean setting (See the short blurb for this in Traefik's [Commons](https://docs.traefik.io/configuration/commons/) documentation).

I haven't verified this, but I believe `--insecureSkipVerify=true` would be the correct flag to pass in your `command` stanza for Traefik to enable this functionality.

Please note that this will affect all backend connections, and can open you up to man-in-the-middle attacks. Issue [#3038](https://github.com/containous/traefik/issues/3038) on Traefik's GitHub repository tracks a design idea that would make this configurable per back-end. Feel free to upvote or issue a PR for this feature.